# Tcl extensions: Life Cycle of extensions' ClientData

Tags: tcl, cycle

Non-trivial native extensions will require per-interpreter data
structures that are dynamically allocated.

I am currently using Tcl_SetAssocData, with a key corresponding
to the extension's name and an appropriate deletion routine,
to prevent this memory from leaking away.

However, Tcl_PkgProvideEx also allows one to record such
information.  This information can be retrieved by
Tcl_PkgRequireEx.  Associating the extension's data structures
with its package seems more natural than in the "grab-bag"
AssocData; yet the Pkg*Ex routines do not provide an
automatically invoked deletion routine.  So I think I need
to stay with the AssocData approach.

For which situations were the Pkg*Ex routines designed for?

Additionally, the Tcl Library allows one to install
ExitHandlers and ThreadExitHandlers.  Paraphasing the
manual, this is for flushing buffers to disk etc.

Are there any other situations requiring use of ExitHandlers?

When Tcl calls exit, are Tcl_PackageUnloadProcs called?

Answer (score 1):

The whole-extension ClientData is intended for extensions that want to publish their own stub table (i.e., an organized list of functions that represent an exact ABI) that *other* extensions can build against. This is a very rare thing to want to do; leave at NULL if you don't want it (and contact the Tcl core developers' mailing list directly if you do; we've got quite a bit of experience in this area). Since it is for an ABI structure, it is *strongly* expected to be purely static data and so doesn't need deletion. Dynamic data should be sent through a different mechanism (e.g., via the Tcl interpreter or through calling functions via the ABI).

Exit handlers (which can be registered at multiple levels) are things that you use when you have to delete some resource at an appropriate time. The typical points of interest are when an interpreter (a `Tcl_Interp` structure) is being deleted, when a thread is being deleted, and when the whole process is going away. What resources need to be specially deleted? Well, it's usually obvious: file handles, database handles, that sort of thing. It's awkward to answer in general as the details matter very much: ask a more specific question to get tailored advice.

However, package unload callbacks are only called in response to the `unload` command. Like package load callbacks, they use “special function symbol” registration, and if they are absent then the `unload` command will refuse to unload the package. *Most packages do not use them.* The use case is where there are very long-lived processes that need to have extra upgradeable functionality added to them.

Comment: By “very long-lived” I mean programs that run continuously for months or even years. Tcl tends to get used in places like exotic industrial control systems where this is a major selling point. OTOH, it also means that the only codes that really use this sort of thing are also strictly commercial (and very specialized too)…