# Tcl extension: Understanding and using ClientData

Tags: c, tcl

I am working to update old software (written to build against Tcl/Tk 8.3) so that it builds against more modern distributions. I am taking this as an opportunity to learn about C and Tcl, both of which I had never programmed in when this project began. So, I'm very novice.

One of the most confusing things for me in learning about the Tcl API is `ClientData`. Many functions in the API take it as an argument, but the C extension almost never uses it. I got the impression from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9610148/1277193) that the global definition is rarely used:

> The whole-extension ClientData is intended for extensions that want to
>   publish their own stub table ... that other extensions can build against.
>   This is a very rare thing to want to do; leave at NULL if you don't
>   want it.

So it seems that it is basically a `void` parameter that you then need to type cast or handle internally. But there are some places in the code where I need to interact with ClientData (e.g. for Idle Processes, as in the following):

```
typedef struct graph *Graph;

struct graph {
  int       num;
  int       hidden;
  int       needsRedraw;
...
};

flag drawNow(ClientData data) {
  Graph G;
  int g = (int) data;
  if (!(G = lookupGraph(g))) return TCL_OK;
  return drawGraph(G);
}

flag drawLater(Graph G) {
  if (!G->needsRedraw && !G->hidden) {
    G->needsRedraw = TRUE;
    Tcl_DoWhenIdle((Tcl_IdleProc *) drawNow, (ClientData) G->num);
  }
  return TCL_OK;
}
```

The cast to integer results in the following warning when I compile:

```
warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
```

My main confusion is `(ClientData) G->num`---I don't understand what I am casting to, because I don't know what kind of a thing ClientData is. If I look in the Tcl sources, I do not find clarity:

```
tclCompile.h:220:typedef ClientData (AuxDataDupProc)  (ClientData clientData);
tclInt.h:2520:typedef ClientData (TclFSGetCwdProc2)(ClientData clientData);
tclOOInt.h:73:typedef ClientData (TclOO_PmCDCloneProc)(ClientData clientData);
```

A couple of final points: These compiler warnings existed before I started doing any updates to the code. The program appears to work on the old systems where the original code does compile and run. So, I am not sure if this warning amounts to anything... but it spooks me, and as long as I am spending time with the code and learning about C and Tcl, I was hoping to get to the bottom of it.

Apologies in advance if I did not provide enough relevant information. I'm happy to provide more, but this my current best effort at a good question.

Comment: using variables `g` and `G` is a very bad programming practice that can/will lead to misunderstandings and maintenance nightmares.

Comment: I agree---I am living the nightmare. I'm working on improving those aspects as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, `ClientData` means “pointer that Tcl *promises* it won't interpret for you”, and is virtually always something that will get handed back to you in a callback. Treat it like `void *` (which is what it is a `typedef` for).

The answer you refer to is talking specifically about the `Tcl_PkgRequireEx` function, where the `ClientData` stuff is used for passing around references to stub tables. You can use this to pass your own, but it's quite involved. It's a pretty rare thing though; most people never touch on those mysteries.

In general, it's more common to see it used in relation to `Tcl_CreateCommand` or `Tcl_CreateObjCommand`. There, the `clientData` parameter is a pointer that will get passed back to the implementation callback when the created command is called; this is *great* for commands that represent instances of classes and things like that. Tcl uses this for things like procedures; the `proc` command uses the `clientData` to pass a pointer to a structure describing the body script (and other stuff) to the C function that implements procedures. If you know a little bit about Tk, `clientData` is used extensively there to pass the low-level handle to the window structure.

With `Tcl_DoWhenIdle`, it's again a pointer being handed over to the callback. Different signature of callback function, of course, but same basic underlying idea.

If Tcl provided C++ APIs, it would probably do things a bit differently since it's possible to talk about pointers to an instance method in that language. But Tcl's API is a C API, so everything has to work like this.

Comment: Thanks for this. Thinking of it like a callback is helpful.